# Вызывать методы модели из модели представления

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Доброго времени суток! Начал изучать WPF и столкнулся с проблемами в понимании шаблона mvvm. Везде говорится что в приложении выделяются три составляющие модель, модель представления и представление. И модель представления не должна выполнять бизнес логику. В этой ситуации я не могу понять как в таком случае вызывать методы модели из модели представления. Скажем у меня есть View (xaml) которое представляет собой таблицу с данными. Я хочу реализовать стандартные операции по отображению, добавлению, удалению и редактированию данных таблицы. Но не могу понять как это сделать если в модели представления нельзя выполнять бизнес логику. В чем я не прав?

Answer (score 5):

Используя Binding к командам в Вашей ViewModel. Например,

```
// View
<Button Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" />
// В ViewModel
public ICommand SearchCommand
{
    get {return new RelayCommand(Search, CanSearch);
}
// RelayCommand это хелпер из MVVM Light пакета
```

Однак очень немного стандартных компонентов WPF поддерживают вызов через `Command`. Чаще всего приходится [переопределять события](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868589/mvvm-light-adding-eventtocommand-in-xaml-without-blend-easiery-way-or-snippet)

По поводу конкретно операций с данными в таблице - обычно удаление, редактирование, удаление (CRUD-операции) выполняются не переопределением событий, скажем, `DataGrid'a`, а обработкой события `CollectionChanged` привязанной к свойству `DataGrid'a` `ItemSource` коллекции элементов.

Если хорошо с английским (у меня не очень, но почти всё понял:)), советую посмотреть  [этот курс](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/building-real-world-windows8-application-mvvm) от Pluralsight.